# getting error while trying to install sklearn lib in python version 3.6.4

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

i am trying to install sklearn lib in my system using "pip install sklearn" in the command window.

I am using python version 3.6.4.

but i am getting the following error as shown in the attached picture-

[image: error message]

the scikit-learn lib is giving error while installing

Kindly help me in solving this issue.

Comment: How are you executing this? From your command-prompt or an administrator elevated command-prompt?

Comment: i am executing from command prompt , previously it was working fine but now only i am facing this issue @VivekKumar

Comment: Please don't include error messages as images, since those are useless for anyone trying to search solution for the same error message

Answer (score 0):

i have updated the cloudpickle version now it is working fine.

using pip install cloudpickle